# Why there is a border box on certain photos in Capture One workspace?

Tags: fujifilm, capture-one, fujifilm-x-t20

I am using Capture One Express Fujifilm 12. Some photo, when they are selected while the crop tool is active (crop icon is in orange color), there is a border around the photo.

[image]

The border disappears when I choose other tool, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

My questions:

1. Why this only appear for a certain set of photo? I used the same camera  system (Fuji x-t20) for all my photo in this catalog.

Second screenshot is attached to show the effect on  several photos in the carousal

[image]

2. How the size of the border size is decided? Does it has anything to do with the any parameter I have used for the photo shoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change to a different tool, the part of the image you have selected (that is, the part inside the border box) is expanded to fill the space. The part you have not selected (that is, the part outside the crop you have selected) is no longer shown.

If you have not selected a crop, then the camera has done it automatically. Many mirrorless cameras will do this at wider angle focal lengths to reduce the amount of geometric distortion, vignetting, and other aberrations that are more pronounced on the edges and corners.

In order to make the lenses used with such cameras smaller and lighter, the manufacturers have elected to use less optical correction in the lenses and do more correction via the processing of the image. The practice is very common with Micro Four-Thirds system cameras, but has also begun appearing in APS-C and even Full Frame mirrorless cameras.

Comment: It's not just common with Micro Four Thirds — it's *expected* and an intentional part of the mount's design philosophy.

Comment: @mattdm That should make it extremely common, shouldn't it?